# Aligning text under various images side by side

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm having trouble aligning these elements side by side with text under them. I tried display flex, display inline block, display block but anything works.
(thanks for the user who suggested flexbox. it was a good idea.)
can you help me, please? Thank you

This is my code

```css
.titlebox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300;
  background-color: #6cbf49;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.heroimg {
  width: 100%;
}

.items {}

.container {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#circle1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

#circle2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

#circle3 {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="titlebox">
    <br>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
    <h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
    <br>
  </div>
  <img class="heroimg" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/any">

  <div class="item">
    <div id="circle1" class="container">
    </div>
    <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum</p>

    <div id="circle2" class="container">
    </div>
    <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum/p>

      <div id="circle3" class="container">
      </div>
      <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum</p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to do.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fXQb.png)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used flexbox for you. I am more comfortable with it. I just did what was your main problem, you could still optimize it. I just added cirlce and lorems inside a new div to apply flex property in item class.

```css
.titlebox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300;
  background-color: #6cbf49;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.heroimg {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#circle1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

#circle2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

#circle3 {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlebox">
    <br>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
    <h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
    <br>
</div>
<img class="heroimg" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/any">

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <div id="circle1" class="container">
    </div>
    <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div>
     <div id="circle2" class="container">
        </div>
        <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>

     <div>
        <div id="circle3" class="container">
        </div>
        <p class="texto">Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much!